# Visual Studio 2010 ditched Wix?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

Not sure I heard this right, but VS2010 no longer has support for Wix?

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Microsoft was considering adding *built-in* WiX support to VS2010, but they changed their minds.

Nothing has changed since earlier versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Straight from Rob Mensching: [Visual Studio will not ship the the Wix toolset](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/4/1/Visual-Studio-will-not-ship-the-WiX-toolset-contributes-only)

Comment: Rob's artical is posted on April 01, 2009... smell fishy??

Comment: [No; it's real](http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2009/12/14/building-setup-and-deployment-packages-in-vs-2010.aspx).

Comment: ok let's assuming that Rob means what he said.... just to clarify, is that mean if you using VS2010 + TFS 2010 then there's no way you be able to use WIX?